# DISM is breaking Office 365 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365, dism, imagex

Usually we setup a computer, install all the needed apps, then use sysprep and DISM to create an image of a computer. However, it seems DISM is breaking Office 365 2016.

```
Sysprep and reboot - Office works
Sysprep and DISM, then apply the image - Office throws error
Sysprep and imagex - Office throws error
```

Error that I am getting:

```
This app can't run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this? DISM is using the default exclude list. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: If you are getting, "This app can't run on your PC", it means your running a 64-bit version of Office on a 32-bit installation of Windows.

Comment: @ramhound That is not the case though. I am using a 32 bit version of office and a 64 bit version of Windows. Like I said, it works fine before DISM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Office Deployment tool to deploy it?  If you not, you want to use that, and make sure you use a silent install so it doesn't activate on installation.

When installing it in the image - make sure you don't run it before you sysprep it.  Test the installation after you have prepped the image.

Comment: Yes.. doing all that except silent. You don't have to make it silent to keep it from trying to activate.